# Twitter bootstrap popover is broken

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

**Note:**

- jQuery 1.9.1
- Bootstrap 2.3.1
- WordPress 3.6 Beta 1 - This issue only happens in WordPress 3.6 Beta

It seems that popovers are broken in the latest version of wordpress, I have the html for the element with the popover attached, along with the jquery that makes the popover work.

**image**

[image]

In case you can't see it, the arrow for the pop over is moved to left and practically opaque

**HTML for that particular element:**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" class="regular" name="aisis_options[posts_display]" value="regular_posts" checked=""> Display normal index of posts. 
        <a href="#" id="regularPosts" rel="popover" data-content="This is a regular list of posts, it comes with a sidebar and pagination." data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Display as Regular Listing">
            <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
       </a>
    </label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#regularPosts").popover({ html : true });
```

I don't know what else to show you as I cant give you admin access to my WordPress "live" dev environment.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the conflict between the two stylesheets (Bootstrap & Wordpress load-styles.php) appeared on *WordPress 3.6 Beta 1*.

In this beta version, they apparently added the class `.arrow` which is also used by Twitter Bootstrap Popover.

### How did I fix it?

1. **bootstrap.min.js**: replace `<div class="arrow">` with `<div class="popover-arrow">`
2. **bootstrap.min.css**: mass replace `.arrow` with `.popover-arrow`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap asks you to download the popover plugin as well, so make sure you have that implemented. Or even go to the customize bootstrap page, and make sure that your options **are** selected.

Answer (score -1):

Well actually their is no problem in your code you have implemented it correct, the problem is that **twitter bootstrap css and wordpress css is crashing,** you have to customize it by making bootstrap css, try to remove wordpress css or make bootstrap css as `!important`... May this trick works for you...